# The number of subsets of cardinality less than $\kappa$ of a cardinal $\kappa$ is $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $L=\bigcup_{\alpha \in Ord} L_\alpha$ be Godel's constructible universe and thus $L \models GCH$. Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and $S:=\{A \subseteq \kappa : \#A < \kappa \}$. Is it true that $L \models \#S=\kappa$? ($\#S \ge \kappa$ trivially.)

My reasoning:
Assuming $V = L$, we have $A \in L_\kappa \iff A$ bounded in $\kappa$ (i.e. $\exists \beta < \kappa. A \subseteq \beta$). If $A \subseteq \kappa$, $\#A < \kappa$ and the cofinality $cf(\kappa)=\kappa$, then $A$ needs to be bounded. Hence $A \in L_\kappa$, but $\#L_\kappa = \kappa$ and so $\#S=\kappa$ when $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal.

Comment: If $\kappa =\aleph_1$ then certainly $\#S\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$, which may be $>\kappa$.

Comment: The true comment above relates to the original question where I did not include the assumption of $GCH$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, even assuming $\sf GCH$, unless we also add that $\kappa$ is *regular*.

If $\kappa$ is regular (and assuming $\sf GCH$ of course), we have that $2^{<\kappa}=\kappa$, and then by [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272907/is-this-proof-that-kappa-kappa-kappa-when-2-kappa-kappa-correct/) the result follows.

If $\kappa$ is singular, e.g. $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)=\lambda<\kappa$, then there are $\kappa^\lambda$ subsets of size $\lambda$, but Koenig's theorem tells us that $\kappa<\kappa^\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  Let $\kappa$ be a successor and $\lambda$ be the cardinal preceeding $\kappa$.  $\kappa$ has a subset of size $\lambda$, which has $2^\lambda$ subsets of size $\lt \kappa$. We know it is consistent that $2^\lambda \gt \kappa$

Comment: I forgot to mention I work in Godel's constructible $L$ and hence $2^\lambda = \lambda^+ = \kappa$.